# Find number of rows during a commun interval

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have an employees list and I log inside "log" table the beginning and the end of the employee working day. Example:

| ID | NAME | BEGINTIME | ENDTIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mary | 05/04/2021 07:10 | 05/04/2021 10:10 |
| 2 | John | 05/04/2021 09:10 | 05/04/2021 14:10 |

And I want to search: how many employees where working at the same time (interval) and the number of them (if more than 1) and sort them from max to min.
Example: Mary and John were working at the same time May 4th from 09:10 to 10:10, before 09:10 Mary was alone, then John came at 10:10 and they were two employee working at the office (the max in that example) then Mary left the office at 10:10 and John was alone.
The point is due to COVID19, I want to know for on a specific date (May 4th in that example) when we had the more employees working in the office at the same time, to split them to lower that max.
Exepected result (the first row is to define the aim) :

| MAXEMPLOYEES | FROMBEGINTIME | TOENDTIME | LISTAGG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm | dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm | ... |
| 2 | 05/04/2021 09:10 | 05/04/2021 10:10 | Mary, John |

I really don't know where to start, maybe I thought, find all the log for the May 4th (let's say 1000 row) and loop, first row then loop again to the other logs and if `MYSELECTEDROWBEGINTIME >= NthBEGINTIME AND MYSELECTEDROWENDTIME <= NthENDTIME` and loop to my list and then go the 2nd row etc.

Comment: By `same interval` you mean: every record that has `BEGINTIME = 04/04/2021 00:00` and `ENDTIME = 04/04/2021 23:59`?

Comment: @T0ny1234 we keep all the logs for each day of the year but yes the interval will be only on one day so 00:00 to 23:53, the point is to be able to say OK we had 234 people working at the same time from 12:00 to 12:30, then 140 people from 16:00 to 17:00 etc

Comment: You can try like this: `SELECT * FROM LOG WHERE BEGINTIME > '04/04/2021 00:00' AND ENDTIME < '04/04/2021 23:59';` I think this will work.

Comment: If Mary worked from 10:00 to 12:05, would she be included in the interval 12:00 to 12:30?

Comment: @T0ny1234 in that case I only will have all the employees during the day, so for example 1000 whatever their planning, I what to have : on May 4th if have 1000 (COUNT(*)) employees working that day

Comment: @Junjie yes, example If I have Mary working in the office from 10:00 to 12:05 and John working from 11:00 to 14:00, I want to have -> 2 employees max working at the same time from 11:00 (Mary was alone before John came at 11:00) to 12:05 (Mary left office at 12:05 then John was alone) (we can exclude when only 1 person is working only).
`Example :
EMPLOYEES   FROM   TO       LISTAGG
450                   08:00     17:00   Mary, John, Charles, Malik, Nina...
100                   17:00     21:00   Robert, Lisa, Frank...`

Comment: @Dimitri. Please post additional information, like above, as updates to the original question. Do not put them in comments.

Answer (score 0):

For 12-12:30 interval, you can start working on this query:

```
select count(*) employees_count
from log
where begintime<to_date('05/04/2021 12:30','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI')
  and endtime>to_date('05/04/2021 12:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI');
```

I'm assuming that the `begintime` and `endtime` are of `date` type. In general, your condition should be `begintime<interval_endtime and endtime>interval_begintime`.

---

For your example output in your original post, you may need a table for the time interval to be `join`ed to `log`, which would look like this:

| int_id | int_from | int_to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 09:10 | 10:10 |
| 2 | 12:00 | 12:30 |

and your query for May 4, 2021 can be something like this:

```
select count(*) maxemployee,
  int_from frombegintime,
  int_to toendtime
from (
    select log.id, log.begintime, log.endtime,
      tint.int_from, tint.int_to
    from log
      join time_interval tint
        on log.begintime<to_date('05/04/2021 '||tint.int_to,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI')
          and log.endtime>to_date('05/04/2021 '||tint.int_from,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI')
  ) t
group by int_from, int_to
```